# Where are file/folder names stored?

Tags: hard-drive, storage

If I were to have a file with no data in it, it would be 0 bytes. However the file I have just created has a file name. Where and how is that data stored on the drive? Is there a difference between the way Windows and Linux stores file/folder names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, the meta information about a file is stored in the [Master File Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365230(v=vs.85).aspx).  There is at least one entry in the MFT for every file on an NTFS file system volume, including the MFT itself. All information about a file, including its size, time and date stamps, permissions, and data content, is stored either in MFT entries, or in space outside the MFT that is described by MFT entries.

It works similarly on Linux, however Linux has access to a lot more file systems than Windows and NTFS.